# How to share runnable developer environments StackOverflow with Codenvy

Tags: angularjs, codenvy

Just a test to see if I can embed a Codenvy Developer Environment to share in my Stack Overflow post!

```html
<iframe name="factory-iframe" width="100%" height="600px" src="http://ide3.cf.codenvy-stg.com/factory?v=1.2&vcs=git&vcsurl=http%3A%2F%2Fide3.cf.codenvy-stg.com%2Fgit%2Fdc%2Fac%2Fea%2Fworkspaceiach7nmhqiw2etzp%2Fangular-todoMVC&projectattributes.pname=angular-todoMVC&projectattributes.ptype=AngularJS&projectattributes.runnername=javascript-webapp-grunt&action=openproject&warnonclose=true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a test too. I need it to debug the Codenvy Environment embedded in stackoverflow.

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="500" src="http://nightly.codenvy-stg.com/ws/gavrikvetal/test-PHP-project" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

#

Try to embed a Factory button for non-encoded factory.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" style="advanced" src="http://nightly.codenvy-stg.com/factory/resources/factory.js" url="http://codenvy.com" logo="http://nightly.codenvy-stg.com/factory/resources/codenvy.png"></script>
```

#

```html
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-top-navigation" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html" style="border: 0; width:130px; height:20px;"></iframe>
```